# cannot unbind key event listener from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent

Hey I have a problem with a grid I am using in Javascript. I'll try tell you what I've tried first. Basically it has a key event for the button delete attached to it. However I want to override this and do something else for this specific keyup event. There is other keyevents that need to stay but I need to change what happens when the delete button  is pushed when I have a row selected.

I've tried a couple of things including targeting it with bind and unbind but nothing seems to work.

I attached an alert to the delete function to fire showing what element is firing the function and it's coming back with dataGrid.

What I was thinking is that the other one is attached after or before so I tried unbinding from both parent and child but no luck.

[image]

Also I tried stop propogation but no luck.

```
                   $(".divDataGrid")
                    .keyup(function(event) {
                        console.log("seamus");
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        // Do something
                    });
```

However none of this works. Has anyone out there run into a similar problem or has anyone an idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: From docs, _As the `.keyup()` method is just a shorthand for `.on( "keyup", handler )`, detaching is possible using `.off( "keyup" )`._

Comment: You need to unbind with a reference to the function

Comment: The function is defined in another script so when I do reference that function I'm getting reference error of div is not defined and when I drill down further in the console I'm finding that the event handler has no name set. I'l attach a pic on the original question for you to see

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried `.unbind('keyup')` ?

Comment: Ya but no luck.....

Comment: I would do `.off("keyup")` first to make sure you can unbind all the handlers. Then hover over function(e) in your screenshot, it should show you the code which should help you track down the function. That should help you reference it, and as a last resort you could (not recommended) change the function so it does what you want.

Comment: I tried this targeting all tr's in the page and still I can't detach the event handler. It's really weird it seems I can't get rid of it.

Comment: So basically I can target the elements and remove them but for some reason I can't get rid of the event listeners.